# Target href in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to place a link in the title, which is essentially the selected anchor href, with a prefix. How could I do the following? I want to be able to get this.href on the selected anchor element.

```
$(".gallery-module > li > a").fancybox(
{
    title       : '<a href="'+ this.href + '-large">DOWNLOAD</a><br> High Resolution File, 300dpi'
});
```

Comment: And what's the problem, what's going wrong?

Comment: Do you have [live demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we could see, and play with?

Comment: So, did you solve your issue? any feedback to the answers provided?

Answer (score 0):

When you're binding fancybox:

```
$(".gallery-module > li > a").fancybox({
    title: '<a href="'+ this.href + '-large">DOWNLOAD</a><br> High Resolution File, 300dpi'
});
```

`this` isn't the matching `<a>` element, `this` is probably `window` so `this.href` isn't the `<a>`'s `href` attribute, `this.href` is (probably) `window.href` and that's not what you want in the title.

If you want to use information from the link in the fancybox, you'll can iterate over the set of matching elements using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and bind fancybox to each `<a>` separately:

```
$('.gallery-module > li > a').each(function() {
    // 'this' will be the <a> in here
    $(this).fancybox({
        title: '<a href="'+ this.href + '-large">DOWNLOAD</a><br> High Resolution File, 300dpi'
    });
});
```

Inside the `$('.gallery-module > li > a').each` callback, `this` will be the `<a>` you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using fancybox v1.3.x, aren't you?

With that version, you can't refer to `this.href` directly unless it is within a callback function. In your case you can use the `titleFormat` option for a customized title like

```
$(".gallery-module > li > a").fancybox({
 titleFormat: function(){
  return '<div class="newTititleWrap"><a href="'+ this.href + '-large">DOWNLOAD</a><br> High Resolution File, 300dpi</div>'
 } 
});
```

Notice that I wrapped the customized title in a `DIV` with *class* = `newTititleWrap` (or whatever you prefer) that you can style using `css` later on.

**UPDATE**: I missed the tag `fancybox-2` (my bad). For fancybox v2.0.6 use the `beforeShow` callback option like:

```
 $(".gallery-module > li > a").fancybox({
   beforeShow : function() {
    this.title = '<div class="newTititleWrap"><a href="'+ this.href + '-large">DOWNLOAD</a><br> High Resolution File, 300dpi</dv>';
   } 
 }); // fancybox
```

I will let posted the solution for v1.3.4 in case it helps somebody else.

Comment: you are right, I missed the tag "fancybox-2" (my bad) ... will edit the answer.